# Python class and array interaction

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, class, sorting

So the basic idea is to make a "phonebook" type deal using classes and I'm not sure how it would interact with arrays.

```
class Person:
name = None
b_year = None
phone = None
```

So that is supposed to be the base. Then I want to be able to use

```
array[0].name #The name of the first person
array[1].phone #Number of the second person etc.
```

What I'm not sure about is how the get this interaction between the two. Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is, or why you think you need special interaction code  - it seems you just want to have a list of `Person`s?

Comment: Not special interaction code. I just don't know how to do 
array[0].name
array[0].phone 
etc.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to create arrays (though you should prefer using lists in this case) in Python? You can find plenty tutorials about that online

Comment: Below was the solution! I was not aware that arrays != lists since in my language they are one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, b_year, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.b_year = b_year
        self.phone = phone


p1 = Person(name="Jedrzej", b_year="1882", phone="321432555")
p2 = Person(name="Michael", b_year="1282", phone="321432553")
arr = [p1, p2]
print(arr[0].name)
```

This prints `Jedrzej` for me.

I think you should read about classes in Python, for example here: 
http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html

Comment: Yup, this works. My class material has nothing on the def __init__ stuff and that seems to be what I'm missing. Thanks for the material too!